# how to change the value of a int CountDown [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I have a counter that is subtracted every second, how can I add more time to the freetime variable when I click on the add time button?

if I add the variables before clicking the start button it works, but once the counter is active it does not add more time to the counter

```
 TextView count_txt;
 Button start_button,moretime_button;
 int freetime = 1800000;
 String time;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.count_layout);

    CountActivity.this.setTitle("CountDown");

    //find view
    start_button = findViewById(R.id.startcount_button);
    count_txt = findViewById(R.id.textView_count);
    moretime_button = findViewById(R.id.button_moretime);


    moretime_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //add button


        }
    });


    start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(netTime,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                     time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"Time Remaining" + "\n" + "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)%60,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)% 60,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)% 60);

                    count_txt.setText((time));
                    netTime--;

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    count_txt.setText("FINISH!!!");



                }

            }.start();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/orbitalsonic/SonicCountDownTimer) you can start, stop, pause, add & subtract the timer in your code. This is a simple library you can add in your project or add a simple module to your project. Here is an example code

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var countDownTimerWithPause: SonicCountDownTimer
    private lateinit var progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator
    private lateinit var tvTimerCountFinished: TextView
    private lateinit var tvTimerCountTotal: TextView
    private lateinit var tvTitleSec:TextView
    private lateinit var btnAddSec: Button
    private lateinit var btnReset: Button
    private lateinit var btnPlayPause: FloatingActionButton

    private var timeSec: Int = 10

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initViews()
        clickMethod()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun initViews() {
        progressIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progress_indicator)
        tvTimerCountFinished = findViewById(R.id.tv_timer_count_finished)
        tvTimerCountTotal = findViewById(R.id.tv_timer_count_total)
        tvTitleSec = findViewById(R.id.tv_title_sec)
        btnAddSec = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_sec)
        btnReset = findViewById(R.id.btn_reset)
        btnPlayPause = findViewById(R.id.btn_playpause_timer)

        initCountdownTimer()

        tvTimerCountFinished.text = "\"00"
        tvTimerCountTotal.text = "|\"$timeSec"
        tvTitleSec.text = "$timeSec"

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun clickMethod() {
        btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener {
            if (countDownTimerWithPause.isTimerRunning()){
                if (countDownTimerWithPause.isTimerPaused()) {
                    countDownTimerWithPause.resumeCountDownTimer()
                    btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24)
                } else {
                    countDownTimerWithPause.pauseCountDownTimer()
                    btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_24)
                }
            }else{
                countDownTimerWithPause.startCountDownTimer()
                btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24)

            }

        }
        btnAddSec.setOnClickListener {
            if (!countDownTimerWithPause.isTimerRunning()){
                timeSec+= 10
                progressIndicator.max = timeSec
                countDownTimerWithPause.setCountDownTime((timeSec*1000).toLong())
                tvTimerCountTotal.text = "|\"$timeSec"
                tvTitleSec.text = "$timeSec"
            }

        }

        btnReset.setOnClickListener {
            countDownTimerWithPause.stopCountDownTimer()
            timeSec = 10
            progressIndicator.progress = 0
            tvTimerCountFinished.text = "\"00"
            tvTimerCountTotal.text = "|\"$timeSec"
            tvTitleSec.text = "$timeSec"
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun initCountdownTimer() {
        var mCount: Int
        progressIndicator.max = timeSec
        countDownTimerWithPause =
            object : SonicCountDownTimer((timeSec * 1000).toLong(), 1000) {

                override fun onTimerTick(timeRemaining: Long) {
                    mCount = timeSec - (timeRemaining / 1000).toInt()
                    progressIndicator.progress = mCount
                    tvTimerCountFinished.text = "\"$mCount"
                    tvTimerCountTotal.text = "|\"$timeSec"

                }

                override fun onTimerFinish() {
                    btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_24)

                }


            }


    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        countDownTimerWithPause.cancelCountDownTimer()
    }
}
```

**SonicCountDownTimer.kt**

```
abstract class SonicCountDownTimer : SonicCountDownTimerListener {
    /**
     * To maintain Timer start and stop status.
     */
    private var isTimerRunning = false

    /**
     * To maintain Timer resume and pause status.
     */
    private var isTimerPaused = false

    /**
     * Timer time.
     */
    private var mTime: Long = 0
    private var localTime: Long = 0
    private var timeInterval: Long = 0
    private var mHandler: Handler? = null

    constructor() {
        init(0, INTERVAL.toLong())
    }

    constructor(timeInMillis: Long) {
        init(timeInMillis, INTERVAL.toLong())
    }

    constructor(timeInMillis: Long, intervalInMillis: Long) {
        init(timeInMillis, intervalInMillis)
    }

    /**
     * Method to initialize [SonicCountDownTimer].
     *
     * @param time:     Time in milliseconds.
     * @param interval: in milliseconds.
     */
    private fun init(time: Long, interval: Long) {
        setCountDownTime(time)
        setTimeInterval(interval)
        initSonicCountDownTimer()
    }

    private fun initSonicCountDownTimer() {
        mHandler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                super.handleMessage(msg)
                if (msg.what == MSG) {
                    if (!isTimerPaused) {
                        if (localTime <= mTime) {
                            onTimerTick(mTime - localTime)
                            localTime += timeInterval
                            sendMessageDelayed(mHandler!!.obtainMessage(MSG), timeInterval)
                        } else stopCountDownTimer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to check whether the timer is running or not
     *
     * @return: true if timer is running, else false.
     */
    fun isTimerRunning(): Boolean {
        return isTimerRunning
    }

    /**
     * Method to start the CountDownTimer.
     */
    fun startCountDownTimer() {
        if (isTimerRunning) return
        isTimerRunning = true
        isTimerPaused = false
        localTime = 0
        mHandler!!.sendMessage(mHandler!!.obtainMessage(MSG))
    }

    /**
     * Method to stop the CountDownTimer.
     */
    fun stopCountDownTimer() {
        isTimerRunning = false
        mHandler!!.removeMessages(MSG)
        onTimerFinish()
    }

    /**
     * Method to cancel the CountDownTimer.
     */
    fun cancelCountDownTimer() {
        isTimerRunning = false
        mHandler!!.removeMessages(MSG)
    }

    /**
     * Method to check whether the CountDownTimer is paused.
     *
     * @return: true if CountDownTimer is paused else false.
     */
    @Synchronized
    fun isTimerPaused(): Boolean {
        return isTimerPaused
    }

    /**
     * To pause the timer from Main thread.
     *
     * @param isPaused: true to pause the timer, false to resume.
     */
    @Synchronized
    private fun setTimerPaused(isPaused: Boolean) {
        this.isTimerPaused = isPaused
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to pause the timer.
     */
    @Synchronized
    fun pauseCountDownTimer() {
        setTimerPaused(true)
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to resume the timer.
     */
    @Synchronized
    fun resumeCountDownTimer() {
        setTimerPaused(false)
        mHandler!!.sendMessage(mHandler!!.obtainMessage(MSG))
    }

    /**
     * Setter for Time.
     *
     * @param timeInMillis: in milliseconds
     */
    fun setCountDownTime(timeInMillis: Long) {
        var timeInMillis = timeInMillis
        if (isTimerRunning) return
        if (mTime <= 0) if (timeInMillis < 0) timeInMillis *= -1
        mTime = timeInMillis
    }

    /**
     * @return remaining time
     */
    fun getRemainingTime(): Long {
        return if (isTimerRunning) {
            mTime
        } else 0
    }

    /**
     * Setter for time interval.
     *
     * @param intervalInMillis: in milliseconds
     */
    fun setTimeInterval(intervalInMillis: Long) {
        var intervalInMillis = intervalInMillis
        if (isTimerRunning) return
        if (timeInterval <= 0) if (intervalInMillis < 0) intervalInMillis *= -1
        timeInterval = intervalInMillis
    }

    companion object {
        private const val INTERVAL = 1000
        private const val MSG = 1
    }
}
```

**SonicCountDownTimerListener.kt**

```
interface SonicCountDownTimerListener {
    /**
     * Method to be called every second by the [SonicCountDownTimer]
     *
     * @param timeRemaining: Time remaining in milliseconds.
     */
    fun onTimerTick(timeRemaining: Long)

    /**
     * Method to be called by [SonicCountDownTimer] when the thread is getting  finished
     */
    fun onTimerFinish()
}
```

**Screen**

[image]